# Change link on migrated posts page for deleted posts to revisions page instead of original page

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, migration

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/posts/migrated/here

> [image: migrated posts]

3d post was deleted on original site. So, when I open [original post](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453264/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B0-delete-%D0%B2-visual-studio-code?noredirect=1), it shows we `404` error.

But on the [moved post](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/999481/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B0-delete-%D0%B2-visual-studio-code) page...

> [image: moved post]

I can click link to original post, and it opens [revisions page](https://rus.stackexchange.com/posts/453264/revisions).

Could you change link on the migration page for deleted posts to revision page instead of original post?